# Is it possible to integrate client side language with server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have designed a search filter using JQuery in .net core web application, by connecting it with sqlserver, which contains > 100k data. But it slows down while loading data.
Is there any way of connecting client side language with server side language?

Comment: There is many way to do. you can do like send filter to server and filtered data get by paging so its show only like 50 record and fetch only 50 record with filter from server then change next paging get another 50 records so its fast in client side and server side.

Comment: @Samavi, what do you mean by "client side language"? Is your data filterable by language?

Comment: JQuery is the client side language. Will it work for such large amount of data as i have added it in .HTML and jquery is using .html tags for searching. Shall i integrate it with server?

Comment: .html file is accessing data from model.cs and then i have used jQuery for filteration.

Comment: Ok, I thought you were talking about browser language like English, Germa etc. You should not be manipulating larger data on the client side. It will slow down the UI and start to hang in the future if memory is low. Seriously consider server side paging. You may consider jquery library like DataTable with server side paging.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the Scroll Paging trick. Depending upon the scroll position, make an AJAX call to the next set of records and have them populated in the grid. That way an additional page click like 1, 2, 3 (page buttons) is not required.

There are a few plugins that help you in this too. Check out https://infinite-scroll.com/